# Strange inequality - WC_BUTTONW not equal to L"Button"?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, equality

I have a Button control wrapper class, which allows you to pass an existing handle to it, provided it is of the `WC_BUTTON` class. I use `GetClassName()` to determine this. But I have a problem, the comments in the code should help describe it:

```
// Initialize from existing handle
Vivify::Button::Button(HWND handle) {
    TCHAR cls[256];
    GetClassName(handle, cls, sizeof(cls));

    Alert(cls);       // MessageBox says "Button"
    Alert(WC_BUTTON); // MessageBox says "Button" also

    Str clsStr = cls;
    Str wcStr  = WC_BUTTON;

    Alert(ToStr<int>(clsStr.length())); // says "6"
    Alert(ToStr<int>(wcStr.length()));  // says "6" also

    // Problem HERE. Evaluates to false. How are they inequal??
    if (cls == WC_BUTTON) {
        SetHandle(handle); // Never gets executed
        m_id = GetDlgCtrlID(handle);
    }
}
```

`Str` is a `std::wstring` by the way, program is in Unicode.
But both the string I get from `GetClassName()` and `WC_BUTTON` are both unicode strings, are both `6` characters long, and both equal `"Button"`, how on earth is the line `if (cls == WC_BUTTON)` returning `false`??

Could someone explain how two seemingly exactly identical strings could be in-equal to each-other?
Or how can I determine if a `HWND` belongs to a button/edit/etc. control?

Comment: Don't compare C strings with ==.

Comment: @chris Well then how should I compare them?

Comment: If still C strings, `strcmp`. Since `vector<char>` and `array<char>` can act like C strings, you could also make `cls` one of those and make another, setting it's `data()` to `WC_BUTTON` and using == on those. I would say `std::string`, but you can't set its buffer directly like that.

Comment: @chris Well it appears `strcmp` only works for `const char *`. So I looked into it and I see there is a Unicode version: `wcscmp`. I see it returns `0` if the strings are identical, does this mean that they only have the same length (so "this" == "that"), or does it *guarantee* that my strings are the same (so "this" != "that")?

Comment: It looks like [_tcscmp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx) is the Microsoft way to select the correct string compare function depending on whether _UNICODE or _MBCS is defined.

Comment: @BrandonMiller, It returns 0 if each character is equal.

Comment: @chris Great, it works perfect. If you'd post that as an answer I'd be more than happy to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not comparing strings, you're comparing addresses. Since the addresses are different, it returns `false`.

Since you need to have the function fill in the buffer, you have two main options:

a) Use C strings and `_tcscmp` (the TCHAR version of `strcmp`):

```
if (_tcscmp(cls, WC_BUTTON) == 0) //0 means equal
```

b) Use a container. `std::vector` and `std::array` let you edit the buffers, unlike `std::string`, but I'll show the latter.

```
TCHAR clsTemp[256];
GetClassName(handle, clsTemp, sizeof clsTemp / sizeof(TCHAR));
std::basic_string<TCHAR> cls = clsTemp;

if (cls == WC_BUTTON) //WC_BUTTON converted to `std::string` to compare
```

The constant C string version of `cls` can then be accessed by `cls.c_str()`.

Note that I've changed your `GetClassName` call to reflect that fact that it takes the length, in characters, of the buffer, not the size in bytes. `TCHAR`'s size might not be one, so it is necessary to divide by that.

Comment: +1 Explains exactly why what I was trying to do didn't work, and gives 2 options. Also points out another flaw in my code and corrects it. Good answer.